# Compile two versions of a document from the same latex source

Tags: latex

How to automatically compile two versions of the same document, for example version without answers for the students and another version with answers for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several packages that allow to conditionally exclude certain parts of the document, for example the `exercise` package.

With TeXstudio, the following magic comment can be used to automatically compile both versions at once (including repeated compilation for cross-references, bibliographies, indices etc.):

```
% !TeX program = latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=% -pretex="\newcommand{\version}{noanswer}" -usepretex % | latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=%_solution -pretex="\newcommand{\version}{}" -usepretex % | txs:///view-pdf "?am)_solution.pdf"

\documentclass{article}

% setting a default value in case it is compiled without the magic comment
\ifdefined\version
\else
\def\version{noanswer}
\fi

\usepackage[\version]{exercise}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exercise}[title={Title},label=ex1]

        question text

    \end{Exercise}

    \begin{Answer}[ref={ex1}]

        solution

    \end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a small bash script to do a dual format.

```
function latex-ans () {
    n=$(basename $1 .tex)  # strip .tex in filename foo.tex -> foo
    ln -s $n.tex $n-ans.tex # create a soft link (for instance foo-ans.tex -> foo.tex)
    pdflatex '\def\withanswer{1} \input{'$n-ans'}' && pdflatex  $n
       % first format the version with answers and then the normal version
    rm $n-ans.tex $n-ans.log
       % remove useless files
}
```

If I have a file foo.tex, this commands formats both versions of the file and generates two pdf: foo.pdf and foo-ans.pdf. Thanks to the renaming of foo.tex through the `ln -s`, it also keeps separate foo.aux and foo-ans.aux to preserve useful information on both versions.

At the latex level, I basically do the same and use the macro \withanswers to configure my packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "More, you do not know which version of file is in a given pdf"?

Comment: If you have a file foo.pdf, is it generated from foo.tex with answers or from foo.tex without answers?

Comment: The one with answers is automatically called `foo_solution.pdf`, I don't see any risk to distribute the wrong one to students

Comment: Right. I missed that. First line of you program is too long! This should solve also the .aux problem.

Comment: As far as I know texstudio does not support line breaks in magic comments - not much that can be done about that