# using command line arguments to include/exclude text sections

Tags: latex

I have a main document defined of which I need to extract different versions. For example, in:

```
\section*{5\\animalia}
\vspace{\oneline}
\includegraphics[page={33}, trim=1cm 0 0 0]{\pdfsource}
\includepdf[page={34-37}]{\pdfsource}
```

the last line would be compiled only if I would run `pdflatex` with the argument `AA`.
There should be around 20 different versions to prepare, so it would be great if I could compile all these in a batch, instead of preparing 20 different files. There are no common elements to select, so the lines from `AA` will all be different ones from `AB` or `AJ`.
I had a look at `\newcommand` and `\xparse`, but I think I didn't find exactly what I needed. Any suggestions?

One other detail: the argument would also be passed to a text line at the start, namely:

```
\subsection*{ARGUMENT}
```

would print as `AA`. I think that is easy to do, but I couldn't also find a concrete example.

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111010/2777074

Comment: Could you please use other combinations of letters in your example? Seeing these 3 combinations of letters combined causes very bad feelings, at least for a German

Answer (score 2):

If you compile the following with

```
pdflatex "\newcommand{\version}{KK}\input{filename.tex}"
```

you can test for the value of `\version`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\ifdefined\version
\else
\def\version{AK}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section{\version}

\ifthenelse{ \equal{\version}{KK} }{
    KK version  
}{
    other version
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.
I'm now trying to implement a second version, where it can use an \or command - but from what I could see from the documentation, it doesn't work?

\ifthenelse{\equal{\version}{AA}} {\includepdf[pages={45}]{\pdfsource}} {}

seems to work, but 

\ifthenelse{\equal{\version}{AA}\or{BB}} {\includepdf[pages={45}]{\pdfsource}} {}

and 

\ifthenelse{\equal{\version}{AA}\or{\version}{BB}} {\includepdf[pages={45}]{\pdfsource}} {}

doesn't really, maybe I need to fiddle around with the brackets until I find the correct connection.

Comment: @jmmmp You could simply nest the ifthenelse, but I think this would be better as a new question

Comment: Ok, I got it. I wasn't repeating the whole condition:
\ifthenelse{\equal{\version}{AA} \OR \equal{\version}{BB}} {\includepdf[pages={45}]{\pdfsource}} {}

This is great, because it makes the code even much simpler.