# latexmk and xelatex from shell script

Tags: latex, csh, xelatex, latexmk

I have asked this question at [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com), but I fear it is closer to a programming question than to a TeX question, hence I'm asking it here.  I hope this is alright. (The original question is [Passing arguments to xelatex using latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511063/18).)

I have a single XeLaTeX source file which can generate two versions of the document depending on whether a certain command sequence `testcs` exists.  I typically do this via a `csh` shell script which generates both versions and which looks like this:

```csh
set file = "Document"
xelatex -jobname="${file}-v1" "\def\testcs{1} \input{${file}.tex}"
xelatex ${file}.tex
```

My document now has an index and typesetting it now requires several passes through `xelatex`.  I would typically use `latexmk`, such as

```
latexmk -pdfxe Document
```

and this works fine, but I now would like to generate the two versions of the document using the script.

In other words, I would like to modify the shell script to use `latexmk`, but I seem unable to pass the arguments to `xelatex`.  I can pass the `-jobname` but I've had no such luck passing the `\def\textcs{1}` via any of the options: `-xelatex`, `-pdfxelatex`, `-pretex`,...

**Question**  Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Can you maybe write a short self-answer to your questions on tex.se to show that the problem is already solved?

Comment: @samcarter  Will do.  Thanks.

Comment: Great! Wish you happy texing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57111010. The trick is that the `-usepretex` option is necessary to tell latexmk to actually do what you specified in `-pretex`

```
set file = "Document"
latexmk -pdfxe -jobname=${file}"-v1" -pretex="\def\testcs{1}" -usepretex ${file}
```