# Same source compiled for customer and developers

Tags: latex

I have a document in Latex with change logs of my software

I would to create 2 output documents from 1 source:

- for the customers, include only short descriptions;
- for the developers, include more details;

I saw in  [Compile two versions of a document from the same latex source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111009/compile-two-versions-of-a-document-from-the-same-latex-source) the use of package `exercise` but there is something more generics?

For example an environment /role1 and /role2 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the linked thread I use the exercise package just as an example. You can use the same mechanism for any document you want.

For example with texstudio:

```
% !TeX program = latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=% -pretex="\newif\ifnotes \notesfalse" -usepretex % | latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=%_notes -pretex="\newif\ifnotes \notestrue" -usepretex % | txs:///view-pdf "?am)_notes.pdf"
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text for everyone

\ifnotes
  notes visible only for devs
\else
  short description for customers
\fi

\end{document}
```

or to be compiled manually with:

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=<filename> -pretex="\newif\ifnotes \notesfalse" -usepretex <filename>
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" -jobname=<filename>_notes -pretex="\newif\ifnotes \notestrue" -usepretex <filename>
```

(replace `<filename>` with the base name of your .tex file)

---

As an alternative approach you could also use this clever trick: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583#a1204